# .* in regexp matching till end of line only

Tags: python

I am having file with following data

```
{
{"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
{"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
{"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
}
```

Below is the code

```
io = open("check")
lines = io.read();

match = re.search(".*", lines, re.M)

print match.group()
```

output is

`{`

I want to match till EOF usign .*

Comment: Which version of Python you are using?

Comment: [(Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the flag `re.DOTALL`:

```
import re
lines = """aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd"""

match = re.search(".*", lines, re.DOTALL)

print(match.group())
```

From the documentation:

> '.' (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a
>   newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any
>   character including a newline.
>
> re.DOTALL Make the '.' special
>   character match any character at all, including a newline; without
>   this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.

Comment: Can you tell me usage of Multiline and DOTALL

Comment: @Nitesh https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL

Answer (score 1):

```
DOTALL is enough to get,

>>> match = re.match(".*", lines, re.DOTALL)
>>> match.group()
'ass\nbss\ncsss\nddd'
>>>
```